# Using the "require:" attribute in order to require several Angular directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to use the `require` attribute in order to require several directives instead of just one?

If so can I pass an array of directives to this `require` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
.directive("...", function() {
    return {
        ...
        require: ["ngModel", "foo", "bar"],
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs.ctrl) {
            var
                ngModelCtrl = ctrl[0],
                fooCtrl     = ctrl[1],
                barCtrl     = ctrl[2];
            ...
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its possible to pass an array or a string. From the source:

`Require another directive and inject its controller as the fourth argument to the linking function. The`require`takes a string name (or array of strings) of the directive(s) to pass in.`